# How can I broadcast a GoogleMaps marker to all connected sockets?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, socket.io

```js
//CLIENT SIDE

// This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
    socket.emit('marker', {'lat': markers[0].position.k, 'long': markers[0].position.D});
    socket.emit('show-marker', addMarker);
  });
}
```

```js
//CLIENT SIDE

// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  clearMarkers();
  markers = [];
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  console.log(location);
  console.log("marker: " + markers[0].position.k + " " + markers[0].position.D);
}
```

```js
//SERVER SIDE

socket.on('marker', function(data) {
  console.log('marker latitude: ' + data.lat + ', marker longitude:' + data.long);
});
```

so far, i am able to console log the latitude and longitude position of when any of player clicks on the map (both on the client and server side).

Comment: Is your question about how to send lat/long via webSocket?  Or is your question how to create a marker on the map for each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `socket.broadcast.emit('show-marker', data)` on the server side. This will emit the 'show-marker' event to every other player. Try this:

**Client:**

```
var markers = [];

// This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    var marker = addMarker(event.latLng);

    //Notice the spelling of longitude "lng"
    socket.emit('marker', {
        'lat': marker.position.k,
        'lng': marker.position.D
    });
});

// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    console.log(location);
    console.log("marker: " + marker.position.k + " " + marker.position.D);

    return marker;
}

//Listen for other players' markers
socket.on('show-marker', addMarker);
```

**Server:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('a user connected');

    //Listen for a marker event from a player
    socket.on('marker', function(data) {

        console.log('marker latitude: ' + data.lat + ', marker longitude:' + data.lng);

        //Broadcast marker location to every player except the one who sent it
        socket.broadcast.emit('show-marker', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: IT WORKED! I'm going to figure out what I did wrong, but just... THANKYOU! :)